# Dispute this review audit

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

I do disagree with this review being bad (after the edit): https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/29712905

It's very detailed, with all the steps, some screenshots and the latest comment goes into this direction too.

---

Also, I've seen this one: [Add an "I don't understand" option for review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/add-an-i-dont-understand-option-for-review-audits)
And I was wondering if I need to create a new post here each time I do disagree with an audit or if there is (or planned at least) something for when this happen.

Comment: Acting on a post outside of the review queue is generally a good way to remove a post from the audit-pool. E.g. if you think the question is good enough and shouldn't have been deleted, vote to undelete. You have enough reputation to cast undelete votes.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have enough experience in the question technology to judge if the question is really good enough to be undeleted and reopened? I find that's usually hard to cast reopen votes unless one is proficient enough in a question tech-stack.

Comment: The question comes with a *huge* scroll bar and two nondescript image links. There's "detailed" and there's "info dump". Are you sure it's the first category?

Comment: @yivi Yep, I can totally cast an undelete vote (just did), my concern is mainly me having to face a false-positive. On the experience level, I did some Java before but I'm not a cucumber expert. Still, the gap and the level of detail of this question is a huge step when comparing the initial question and seems totally fine. Of course, I can also filter with some tech that I am more proficient with (the reopen queue is plenty enough for this) but usually, I do not face any issues beyond me not paying attention enough/it being a false positive.

Comment: The question reads more like a guide than anything else. It just finished off with *"still face same error."* but the error never actually appears in the question. It could really do with being made (by the OP) into an [mre]. (I have no expertise in the tags, so maybe it *does* need that much info?) Certainly putting the error in the question would be an infinite improvement though...

Comment: _"Still, the gap and the level of detail of this question is a huge step when comparing the initial question"_. That's not enough to know if a question should be reopened. "Added more details" could mean "added irrelevant details and noise". It's better to only vote to reopen (or undelete) when once is certain that the post is good enough. An frankly, that requires subject matter expertise. One also needs to be very certain when voting to close or delete, but that, many times, requires no expertise on a subject.

Comment: What I mean is that it's really not fair for you to say this audit is good or not, if you do not have the requisite knowledge to ascertain the quality of the question (e.g. by knowing if it can or it can't be answered).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi the question is mainly a configuration issue. Non descriptive images are not that big of a deal here since the info is already available as text. I could totally edit those small quirks (and usually do) but since this one is deleted, I did not bother with it for bump reasons.

Comment: @yivi I don't find it being noise so far. Also, if people waited to have a really good expertise in a specific domain before giving a good feedback, the traffic of reviewers would be far lower. I've already seen 1400 specific-tag reputation guys missing the point of a question. For me, it looks good enough for a 2nd chance especially when compared to all the reopen cast votes that I see daily (which are really meaningless changes, at best).

Comment: That's not how reopening works. By saying it's "good enough", if you don't actually know if it's good enough, you are hampering the system, not helping. Obviously, for many types of feedback you need a subject matter expert. Otherwise, it's meaningless feedback. (I don't care about tag-score, since you bring that up; just that you personally can judge a question to be of good quality, beyond "feeling they deserve a second shot", which they can always take by posting a better question).

Comment: @yivi alright, I guess I'll dodge [tag:java] questions next time or simply eat the audit and go on. For the day that I do have another false positive in a field I am more proficient in, do I need to post another question here or do I have another way of disputing an audit?

Comment: Again, acting on the post outside of the queue. Voting, generally. Since audits are selected automatically, feedback on the post makes it more/less likely they are picked up as audits. In any case, I find that if one filters by tag, it's **very** difficult to fail an audit.

Comment: @kissu At least the second image does not match any code in the question. "enter image description here" really doesn't clear up whether it should or not. As for the "it's configuration" – the question only shows the base setup and a "you should do this and that" error. For such a long post, I would expect to see the "you should do this and that" code, not some base case from which we have to guess how they implemented the suggestion. TLDR: There are *lots* of gaps that one has to guess.

Comment: @yivi this one does not remove the penalty of eating a warning tho. I am not clicking on "I understand" on the next false positive audit. Since it's automatic, there is a margin of error and a single upvote/undelete vote will probably not change it a lot (on top of being "too late"). I'm not saying that I do fail a lot, I am mainly committed to complete several queues per day every day and this can add up to a ban for a small period of time. Or is it computed as a ratio of passed/failed audits? If it's juste absolute amount of warnings, this is pretty limited for daily reviewers.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi those gaps are failed by 90% of people's questions that I see **daily**. Does that mean that we need to delete 90% of the new questions, especially of newcomers? For me, somebody with 1 rep should benefit from a bit more patience when it comes down to judgement. Of course, it does not grant OP immunity, but seeing somebody coming back to his closed question to update it in the best manner that he can is not something that you see daily. Usually, other people are hard with those people and still downvote them. SO recommends going slow on newcomers, as I do in this reopen queue.

Comment: The recommendation about "going slow" (sic.) on newcomers means "be mindful that the language and tone that use use to address new users is kind", does **not** mean "give new users a pass when it comes to question quality". Not even close. User reputation is irrelevant when judging if a post is good or not for the site. (We are diverting a lot from your original question, but maybe these misconceptions might be what drove you to fail the audit in the first place).

Comment: @yivi having it's question deleted as a newcomer can be pretty hard to face. And SO is not **that** friendly to tell you what is wrong. So yeah, I guess that the day SO allows one guy to just wipe questions, I'll gladly wipe 50 questions per week if not more. As of right now, the ones I am answering do not have enough trafic. Ahh, those lucky newcomers, brace yourself! I still stand that this question is okay so no, your assumption is not correct. I am not deleting this since Ryan just answered but I would have if not.

Comment: _"SO recommends going slow on newcomers, as I do in this reopen queue."_ Nowhere the site says that you should be more lenient regarding question quality or topicality when the author is a new user. Nowhere. Judge the posts as they come, no matter who posted them. Want to help a new user that posted a bad question? Post comments telling them what they should do to fix their questions, if you think it's possible to fix them. Do **not** reopen/undelete a bad question, because you are simply setting them up for failure.

Comment: @yivi we do have divergent points of view here. I am not going to change my behavior regarding how I do handle newcomers because of obvious reasons (trying to help). And I do already help (comments mainly) questions that are not deleted. Still, I don't agree on taking this way of deleting/downvoting newcomers. And I do not reopen/undelete questions that I judge bad, also don't worry I do also downvote/close a lot of poorly asked questions. I'm not daily upvoting garbage questions of newcomers putting 0 effort (as it may seem from what I've told above, I guess?).

Comment: You voted to reopen a question that had already been deleted.  The best way to properly handle questions is to open reviews is to open the question in another tab.  From my perspective voting to reopen a question that had been deleted means you were not paying attention.  As for not clicking on “I understand”, regardless if you do or don’t click on the button, you still fail the audit

Comment: @SecurityHound thanks, I'm already opening a new tab (when I think it's needed hence not all the time). Here, I open the tab, saw it deleted and kinda understood that it being deleted is not a blocker of being opened back (so, un-delete and un-lock it at the same time). As for the button, yeah I did some reviews already, realized it already. I was talking more about the principle of accepting something that is wrong to my eyes (it being an invalid question).

Comment: @SecurityHound You are mistaken: [deleted questions can be reopened without undeleting them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68942920/208273).

Comment: You linked to a question that had never been deleted and is currently closed.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is what I'd call a bug:

#### Questions that never completed a reopen review after editing should not be used as known-bad audits

This [question's reopen review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/29599947) was invalidated with no reviews by the [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) deleting the post on Aug 26 because it was closed and that was 10 days after the last edit.  The only feedback the system had on the edited post was a single downvote on Aug 26.  That's hardly enough evidence for a known-bad audit.

Known-bad audits should either use questions that were not edited after closing or received a full set of "Leave closed" reviews.

Comment: Btw, how is the following case even handled: "2 close votes + major great update to a question + 3rd close vote"? Would be pretty bad to have it just closed without any attention to detail here. This is what it looks like here tbh (didn't took the time to see if it's feasable or not tbh).

Comment: @kissu Looking at the post's [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68755016/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries), it looks to me like the post was closed before any edits.

Comment: There's no way of knowing the detail of when a single close vote was casted tho. Or is there one? It being deleted after the edit is the issue in this specific question. My first comment here was mainly aimed towards other questions.

Comment: @kissu That's correct, but the question was closed Aug 12 at 11:32 and the first edit was Aug 16 at 6:37, so all the close votes were necessarily cast before the edit.  A third close vote cast after a question is fixed _does_ happen, but it's hopefully uncommon: people should evaluate the question as-is and determine whether it still has issues.  And as you note, it's a different problem than what happened here.

Comment: Yeah, there are pros and cons to this 3rd vote closing I guess. Having it as an audit is kinda troublesome IMO, hopefully it does not happen often.